# Can't connect from MacBook to iMac through internet sharing

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

I have an iMac and my MacBook Pro is unable to connect to it through internet sharing.

Is there a way I can check whether my wireless card is working, or diagnose the problem in more depth? I have already tried the usual stuff: from re-creating the connection to wiping the PRAM.

**How do you want to "connect"?**

I want to share my iMacs internet connection.

**What kind of connection are you even creating?**

A straight forward Wifi connection using 128 WEP

**Do you have shared folders that you want to access?**

No

**What IP addresses to the machines have?**

the MacBook Pro is unable to attain an ip from the iMac, though it can see it.

**Can the Macs ping each other via IP?**

No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an apple bug with the driver, which they fixed in Mountain Lion

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

- Switch the firewall off on both machines (if it was on) to see if it helps;
- Try to connect using a different device to the shared connection (another computer, smartphone, iPad, etc.);
- Use an open connection first (no password), before trying with WEP;
- Reverse the roles of the two computers (i.e. try sharing the connection from the MBP to the iMac).

Also, more details might help (OS X version on the machines, whether you are trying to share a wired connection, installed software which might interact with the network connections, etc.)